# Autodetect gitlab branches with jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I'm trying to do a job in jenkins for compile with maven a gitlab branch passed like input parameter.

The problem is that my boss wants, when you are going to execute the job from jenkins, the input parameter let you choose the branch between all the branches detected automatically of your gitlab project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[git parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Parameter+Plugin) let's you choose between tags and/or branches - they are displayed in a listbox when you build the project. You can install it via Jenkins plugin manager. It requires that your project has been built at least once in advance.

Comment: Thanks you guy, i had the plugin installed but it was a old version, i couldn´t select branches. I updated the plugin and all correct. thanks for all :)